# How to append data to a path or object in D3 and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an object that I refer to like this:

```
  d3.json(file, function(error, europe) {
```

but I have some appendix that is variable, i.e. it could change based on the input from a drop down menu. This information goes into topojson in this way:

```
    var europe_path = "nuts1";

    var land = topojson.feature(europe, europe.objects.+"europe_path");
```

but that doesn't work, it throws this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +
```

How can I change the path/object so that it can be dynamic to accommodate that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `europe.objects.+"europe_path"` with `europe.objects[europe_path]`

Comment: What is the error message? And is `europe.objects` an object?